# Trying to figure out horizontal wins for a connect 4 game in python

Tags: python

ive been trying to make a connect four game. As I was following a tutorial it abruptly ended and I wanting to finish it.

Right now im making win functions so the game can see if 4 peices are next to eachother horizontally. Right now i have this and it does give me a win if we put 4 peices in the first four colums. But if we do it on the last four the game continues which it should give the player a win.

(Im new to stack overflow sorry for the bad wording. You should try it yourself on your own IDE)

This snippet is running in html. It is a python program!

```
# Connect Four

# Creates 2d board list
numRows = 6
numCols = 7
board = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ]


### Prints board in 0's for empty boxs, and 1s, and 2s for players


def printBoard():
    for rows in range(0, numRows):
        for cols in range(0, numCols):
            print(board[rows][cols], end=' ')
        print(" ")


# Goes through all rows and checks if the player can place it there, if not it writes one above it

def fillIn(col, player):
    col = col - 1
    for rows in range(numRows - 1, -1, -1):
        if board[rows][col] == 0:
            print("Legal Move")
            board[rows][col] = player
            break


def win():
    if horizWin() or vertWin() or diagWin():
        return True
    return False


def horizWin():
    for row in board:
        for i in range(len(row) - 4):
            window = row[i:i + 4]
            # check if all elements in the row are 1s or 2s
            if window.count(window[0]) == len(window) and window[0] in [1, 2]:
                print("You Win!")
                return True


def vertWin():

    for col in board:
        ()


def diagWin():
    pass


player = 1

while not win():
    col = int(input("Please Select A Colum 1-7: "))

    if col > 7:
        print("That colum is over 7!")

    fillIn(col, player)
    printBoard()
    if player == 1:
        player = 2
    else:
        player = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool project!

Python's `range` excludes the upper bound, meaning `range(n)` produces `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]`, and `range(len(row) - 4)`, like you have, will produce `[0, 1, 2, ..., len(row)-5]`. If you want the last 4 elements of a row (`[row[len(row)-4], row[len(row)-3], row[len(row)-2], row[len(row)-1]]`), you need to start on `i = len(row)-4`. Currently your code doesn't do this, because it has the line `for i in range(len(row) - 4):`. Try changing that to `for i in range(len(row) - 3):`.